# go get fetching a pre-release version always

Tags: go, module

I am trying to wrap my head around go modules.  This is what I have done so far.

- Created a simple module and published it as 0.0.1 on github.
- Referenced the above mentioned module in a separate go project and used it.

so far it works fine.  Now I update the initial module to 0.0.2 and publish it as a release on github.  Now when I try `go get <published module>` it still seems to fetch the original 0.0.1 version and run it.  I also deleted all references to 0.0.1 including in go.mod and go.sum and run `go get` and it still fetches the original 0.0.1 version instead of 0.0.2.

I also tried publishing a major version 1.0.0 and tried to use it, but its still fetching the older 0.0.1 version.  I thought it will automatically fetch the latest version and use that.

My go.mod file also shows the following even for the major version

```
require github.com/user/module v0.0.0-20210223020204-1b5fb712826f // indirect
```

I feel there could be something wrong in the way its being published on git.  Any help, anyone.

Comment: Have you tried using `go get <published module>@latest`

Comment: wow, that worked, just what I wanted, doesn't go get update the module automatically, do I have to give a specific version ?  I'm coming from a node background, which updates automatically

Comment: Please do not assume that _anything_ in Go or its ecosystem works as in NodeJS. It doesn't. If you want to update a dependency you have to _tell_ go get to do so either by giving the exact version you want, `@latest` or set the `-u` flag.  Also: Contrary to most other languages and tools the documentation in Go tends to be good, complete and useful, so if you use `go get` read `go help get` first.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the comments already highlighted the required steps to take, but to capture the information in an answer, here is the relevant snippet from `go help get`

> The -u flag instructs get to use the network to update the named packages
> and their dependencies. By default, get uses the network to check out
> missing packages but does not use it to look for updates to existing packages.

Basically, `go get` will only fetch the versions locked in your `go.{mod,sum}` files and you need to explicitly ask for updates using one of:

```
# upgrade to the latest release
go get -u github.com/user/module

# upgrade to a specific version
go get github.com/user/module@2.0.0

# use the `latest` version alias
go get github.com/user/module@latest
```